# Understanding NTRUEncrypt

Tags: encryption, polynomial-math, ntruencrypt

I have trouble understanding the NTRUEncrypt algorithm. I read the wikipedia page, but I can not understand the [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTRUEncrypt#Public_key_generation) they gave. When I plug in the product of f and f_p onto wolfram, I do not see how the [output](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%20%2b%20x%20%2b%20x%5E2%20-%20x%5E4%20%2b%20x%5E6%20%2b%20x%5E9%20-%20x%5E10%29%20%2a%20%28-1%20%2b%202x%20%2b%202x%5E3%20%2b%202x%5E4%20%2b%20x%5E5%20%2b%202x%5E7%20%2b%20x%5E8%20%2b%202x%5E9%29) relates to any inverse mod p. Can someone please explain the process (and if possible, why it works?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I understand the process now.

In the [corrected output](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%20%2b%20x%20%2b%20x%5E2%20-%20x%5E4%20%2b%20x%5E6%20%2b%20x%5E9%20-%20x%5E10%29%20%2a%20%281%20%2b%202x%20%2b%202x%5E3%20%2b%202x%5E4%20%2b%20x%5E5%20%2b%202x%5E7%20%2b%20x%5E8%20%2b%202x%5E9%29), you have to add the coefficients for X^0 and X^11, X^1 and X^12, and so on, because you are taking it mod (X^11 - 1). The sums of these pairs of coefficients is always equal to 0 mod 3, except for the first one, which is 1 mod 3, as defined by the wikipedia page.